# How can I represent probabilistic grammars in BNF?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, bnf

I've found a grammar online which I want to rewrite to BNF so I can use it in a grammatical evolution experiment. From what I've read online BNF is given by this form:

```
<symbol> := <expression> | <term>
```

...but I don't see where probabilities factor into it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "probabilistic," but classic BNF is very strict and unambiguous.  EBNF has some extensions that simplify some expressions and make others possible, but every grammar engine I've worked with seeks to resolve grammar ambiguity.  Can you show us what you have so far, what your specific problem is?

Comment: @JLH by probabilistic I mean stochastic. I wanted to use this in grammatical evolution experiment, but I'm starting to think that GE isn't meant to be used with stochastic grammars

Answer (score 2):

In a [probabilistic context-free grammar (PCFG)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_context-free_grammar), every production also is assigned a probability. How you choose to write this probability is up to you; I don't know of a standard notation.

Generally, the probabilities are learned rather than assigned, so the representation issue doesn't come up; the system is given a normal CFG as well as a large corpus with corresponding parse trees, and it derives probabilities by analysing the parse trees.

Note that PCFGs are usually ambiguous. Probabilities are not used to decide whether a sentence is in the language but rather which parse is correct, so with an unambiguous grammar, the probabilities would be of little use.

Comment: A PCFG isn't *necessarily* ambiguous. It's unambiguous if the underlying CFG is unambiguous.

Comment: @michael: technically correct, but the probabilities aren't very useful in the absence of ambiguity. Perhaps "almost always" would be a better adjective?